# Optimize Lucene batch indexing

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene.net

This is the question:

Im using Lucene.Net, and Im importing like ~255k documents with ~6 fields each. Ive tried a few things, but the process takes a lot (~1day). Im not using any strange analyzer, just the standard analizer and Im tokenizing only one of the fields. I tried changing the max merge docs and nothing.

Has anyone bumped into this problem?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a different alternative and I've decided to post the result, so If anyone should face the same problem may find this other way to go.

Lucene.net has an interesting feature allowing to merge two indexes, so my idea is to index my content into several smaller indexes and join them using the merge feature.

This has worked for me. I tested this solution indexing WordNet to perform queries on it and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have access to a profiler ([Redgate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) is very good), then:

1. Work out your bottleneck: is it the Lucene code or your data reader?  Comment out the Lucene indexing code, leaving just your data reader.  It should be easy to tell on which side your problem lies.
2. Make sure you're using lucene as built from SVN.  The version 2.9.x from subversion is much better than earlier versions, especially with regards speed of indexing
3. Use the default merge factors etc.  Lucene seems to be much better at this than my attempts at tweaking.
4. Lastly (and perhaps most importantly!) does it matter that indexing is slow?  If you're only going to ever have to do this once or twice a year: I'd say don't worry about it.  (Unless this is a learning exercise or somesuch)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I see all your points and you've made fair observations in all of them. Can you tell me more about the profilers for Lucene? Im interested in that

Comment: I've slightly edited my answer to give a link to the website of the tool I'm most familiar with: it's very good.